# C# If URL path does not exist. Redirect to Notfound.aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms

Hi I am working on a ASPX webform project.
I am implementing a functionality if the URL path does not exist then redirects the user to NotFound.aspx.

I tried searching for relative examples but did not get any idea how I can implement it.

I tried adding code to the master page.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/"+ path)))
                Response.Redirect("~/NotFound.aspx");
```

Any lead can help thank you.

Comment: This won't work because the path that is requested and not exists is the one you put the code in to detect if the page does not exist. Configure this in the web.config: https://serverfault.com/questions/68137/how-to-configure-a-web-config-file-to-allow-custom-404-handling-while-still-disp

Comment: @VDWWD I tried this example, Do need to create an HTML page to redirect or i can still use ASPX.

Comment: you can still use aspx if you want.

Comment: @VDWWD It worked, But it is not displaying my Notfound.aspx page. It's displaying the  default line i think, I am trying to change it But no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @VDWWD for the Help.

This worked for me.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File" >
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404"
               path="/NotFound.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```